# Why did the Spanish Courts 'remove' so many Spanish cyclists from the Operation Puerto investigation?

Tags: doping

Operación Puerto is an ongoing investigation (opened in 2006) by the Spanish police in to the activities of Doctor Eufemiano Fuentes, a sports doctor infamous for supplying professional athletes with performance enhancing drugs and associated training programs. [Wikipedia provides a great summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_Puerto_doping_case).

Looking through the [list of athletes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_Puerto_doping_case#List_of_athletes_named) implicated in the investigation, it does appear that the Spanish courts removed a number of Spanish athletes from the investigation (specifically from 2 Spanish cycling teams). Presumably there was more to this decision than an attempt by the Spanish police to protect Spanish athletes but I'm struggling to find an alternative explanation. Can anyone explain further?

Comment: It seems to me that this is a legal/political question, not a cycling one.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It's a legal/political question of great relevance to cycling. We're happy to accept questions about, for example, what the rules of the road are for cyclists, so I don't see why we shouldn't accept this one.

Comment: They also removed an Australian and a Portuguese and a Colombian had his case dropped by his federation. All four of the Astana riders who aren't listed as removed are Spanish, as are all the other riders who don't have any further information next to their name in the Wikipedia list. So I'm not sure there's any real pattern, here. The majority of the people investigated in Puerto were Spanish, so it doesn't seem surprising that the majority of people whose investigation was terminated were also Spanish.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sounds like an answer - "how to report using misleading statistics"

Comment: So this isn't specific to cycling, and Fuentes is a sports doctor not cycling-specifc, so I suggest this would be better on  https://sports.stackexchange.com/  which is much more general.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better phrased on how to understand WADA and get some governance related tilt. If this is really about the legal system there is a law, but this seems too little law for a law question and too much law for a sports question. No matter what SE - it's also dangerously close to "lets talk about" without a concrete request other than "can anyone explain further" since that's a yes/no question to tie this up with a bow. Maybe rather than presume a thesis - ask a pointed question with an edit while the site to host this is up in the air?